# Convert DateTime to nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with column of the type nvarchar. I'm going through the following parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

and as expected'm getting the error:

> Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

How to convert DateTime to nvarchar?

Comment: `SqlDbType.NVarChar` with `DateTime.Now`? o.O If your column is `NVarChar`, why you send it a `DateTime` value? If you send a  `DateTime` value, why your column is `NVarChar`? You should **always** choose the right data type for your values. Read [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Do not convert `DateTime` to string/nvarchar. Instead pass it as `DateTime`, make sure your field in table is also of type DateTime

Comment: You could always call `ToString()` on the `DateTime` object. But like prevous comments pointed out, bad choice of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like whatever you are trying to do in your database is expecting a parameter called "PointDate" but of type NVarChar.  Of course, you could change that to be a date type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

of if whatever you are doing in the database really has to be a string, then

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

You may have to add a format specifier to that ToString function to match whatever your database is expecting.

Comment: Go for this solution, This answer will solve the issue.

Comment: It works, but does it **help**? You should never use string types to keep date values. Use the proper data type for your columns.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It is not true that one should *never* use string types for date values.  For example, if he is having the database compose an email to a client saying "you placed an order on May 21, 2015", it would be legitimate to have the date in text.  We do not know what he is doing with that date, so we can't say.

Comment: @Gilchrist: Storing a date as string just to avoid formatting you output is a **bad design.** Most date formats are supported out of the box using a simple convert function in sql in almost every rdbms there is. Storing a date as string will always create problems on sorting, indexing, performance and storage space. You should *always* use the appropriate data types.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - You are assuming that "cmd" is a command that just stores the value of the PointDate parameter into a column in the database.  You do not know that.  There is not enough information in his post for you to know that.  Yes, using inappropriate data types is wrong.  But making unwarranted assumptions is usually a bigger and more insidious problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - what if the name of the NVarChar column in his database is "EmailText" or "Comments", and this date is just part of what goes into it?

Comment: @Gilchrist I'm assuming that `@PointDate` will be stored alone in a column, probably called `PointDate`, and is of the **wrong type**. If it was suppose to be stored as a part of a bigger string then it doesn't make sense to send that string part by part to the database - the OP should have build it in the c# and send it as a complete string using a single parameter. building the string in the database when it can be done in c# is amost as wrong as storing the date as nvarchar. Plus, even if that was the case, passing the date as date and casting it to nchar in the database would be better.